# Android - Text Switcher

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a text switcher dynamically but I get the error:

> The method setFactory(ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory) in the type ViewSwitcher is not applicable for the arguments...

Here's my code:

```
TextSwitcher ts = (TextSwitcher) new TextSwitcher(this);
ts.setFactory(this);
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out);
ts.setInAnimation(in);
ts.setOutAnimation(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

The setFactory method expects a [ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory.html) type argument and not Activity (which I presume is your `this`.)

You have 3 options:

1. you can implement your own ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory. you can see an example [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52142491/74/Working-with-ViewSwitcher-Controls).
2. you can use [ViewSwitcher.addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) to dynamically add your child views
3. you can define the child views in your layout xml

Either one should work OK for you.

Comment: Could you expand on option 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity class needs to implement `android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory` interface.